# How can I omit the first character for value in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have this var:

```
Dim number as decimal = -61.52
```

and I want to delete the first character to be like this:

```
61.52
```

I tried to do this. but doesn´t work:

```
number = Trim(Left(number , Len(number ) - 1))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not a `String` so don't try to trim it :)

Comment: I mean to omit the first character for value

Comment: @Lore_98: if i take your title on trust you don't want to remove only the minus, what if the value is `61.52`, do you want `1.52`?

Comment: I want to remove the minus, only that

Comment: @Lore_98 you don't want to remove the first character, you want to remove the minus. that's two completely different things. Math.Abs is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `Math.Abs()`, which forces a number to not be negative.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to treat a number as a string and then do string manipulations on it, you want to use the ToString method on your number. This will let you specify how you want the number formatted.

```
Dim NumberAsString As String
NumberAsString = number.ToString()

NumberAsString = NumberAsString.SubString(1, NumberAsString.Length - 1)
```

Note: you shouldn't rely on the default implementation as it will use the current UI culture and not guaranteed to give consistent results if executed under different cultures than when you developed it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-D